# How do you use a list that was created in another function in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have these two functions.

```
def get_numbers():
    phone_num = []
    df = pd.read_csv('students.csv', names = ['name', 'phone number', 'class time', 'duration'])
    phone = df['phone number'].tolist()
    print(phone)
    for i in phone:
        phone_num.append(i)

def use_num_list():
    print(phone_num)
```

I basically want to use the 'phone_num' list in another function. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Side note, `phone_num = []; ...; for i in phone: phone_num.append(i)` can be simplified to `phone_num = phone.copy()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return it from your function, and then pass it in to your other function.

```
def get_numbers():
    phone_num = []
    df = pd.read_csv('students.csv', names = ['name', 'phone number', 'class time', 'duration'])
    phone = df['phone number'].tolist()
    print(phone)
    for i in phone:
        phone_num.append(i)
    return phone_num

def use_num_list(phone_number):
    print(phone_number)


numbers = get_numbers()
use_num_list(numbers)
```

Also, remember that the names of the objects only exist in their local scope. In other words, the variable name `phone_num` only exist in the function `get_numbers`.

So when you call the function you have to assign the list to a new name, like `numbers = get_numbers()`. Now, `numbers` will contain the list and you'll be be able to access the list within the global scope. From here, you can pass it to other functions.